# Should the "half" in "half-Chinese" be capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

Is it correct to write *half-Chinese* or *Half-Chinese*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write *half-Chinese* and not *Half-Chinese*. In the same way we write *anti-Semitic* and not *Anti-Semitic*.

Comment: Unless it's in a title of course.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be capitalised unless it's in a title.

Comment: Or at the beginning of a sentence, too, but isn't that obvious?